# Keep getting Exceptions on correct Catches

Tags: c#, exception, arguments, try-catch

I am in need of some help with a small problem. 
I've got 2 strings that needs to be put **in order** a parameter box in `Task Scheduler`. But I want to catch the `System.FormatException` that occurs when somebody accidentely switches them.

But whatever happends, I keep getting the same error. I also added a catch in case either one or both of them hasn't been put at all. Because if that happends, a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` error will occur. Basicly my code does the following:

```
try
{
   //Processing the inputted parameters
}

catch(System.FormatException e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

catch(System.IndexOutOfRange.FormatException e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

I tested these two catches separately. But either way I get the error.

I've seen some examples, but those were made specifically for some methods.

If anyone can help me out with this issue, I'd appreciate it! :)

**Edit**

Current catch:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
   streamwriter.Close();
   filestream.Close();
}
```

**Edit**

The error:

```
Unhandled exception: System.FormatException: the format of the input string is incorrect.
at System.Number.StringToNumber < NumberBuffer String str, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean & number, parseDecimal >
at System. Number. ParseInt32 < String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info >
at System. Convert. ToInt32 < String value > at LastWriteAccess_Checker. Program. Main < String [] args >
```

This all refers to the input parameters in the code. One being `int` that gets converted to `string`.

Comment: why not use the catch (Exception ex) {} which catches all?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this

Comment: "But whatever happends, I keep getting the same error."  So you're saying that your `System.FormatException` is not being caught?  It is being caught, maybe your Visual Studio is just breaking on all thrown exceptions.  Goto the menu Debug -> Exceptions in VS and make make sure that the `Thrown` column is unchecked.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention that part. I tried to use the `Exception ex` to catch them all. But that didn't work either.

Comment: Really not sure what you are asking for here.  Your post is full of statements that do not make sense.  For example: "*.. I want it written down to the Console.WriteLine();*", I have no idea what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: How can catching all exceptions not catch all exceptions? are you sure that the issue you are describing is actually causing the issue?

Comment: Maybe I gave a bit too much information. I'll narrow it down: I have 2 strings that are working in order. But I want a error catch whenever someone accidentely switches them. But the catch for the exception is not working.

Comment: Are you sure the code you are testing is up to date with the actual modified source code? I've came to situations similar to this due to being out of sync (all changes I was doing weren't making a difference).

Comment: I've less complicated the information A LOT more, hope this helps a bit.

Comment: You question is unclear. You show perfectly fine code that catches some specific exceptions and write to the console. You then tell us that when your code throws the exception you __get the error__. You have to explain what error it is that you are getting. And when you have done that you will probably realize what your problem is. Obviously, your code will write the exception to the console so that cannot be the error that you are getting.

Comment: "I keep getting the same error." And that error is? You still didn't say what you get instead of what you expected.

Comment: @MartinLiversage I've put the code in the question

Comment: @vascomakker: Have a look at the stack trace of your exception. The exception cannot be thrown inside the `try` block and must originate from somewhere else. You can also try to run your code inside the debugger which then will break when the unhandled exception is thrown.

Comment: @MartinLiversage The debugger told me that the problem was in the conversion of one of the parameters. So I've put the line somewhere else in the code, a few lines lower inside the try, and now it's working! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answered the original question which has now been edited, so it might not be an appropriate answer in light of the edits.**

To catch both exceptions and react to them you can write this.

```
catch (Exception ex)            
{                
    if (ex is FormatException || ex is IndexOutOfRangeException )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
finally
{
    streamwriter.Close();
    filestream.Close();
}
```

You can put a breakpoint at the catch to see what the actual exception being caught is.

You should close resources in the `finally` block, not the `catch` block

Comment: This was the first one I read about on stackoverflow. This didn't help me at all.

Comment: @vascomakker You were trying to combine two different exceptions into one, right?  What do you need help with if this doesn't help you?

Comment: Again @vascomakker are you sure?

Comment: I'm 100% positive. I'ts not about combining the 2 of them. That part comes later. Right now it's about a correct catch for the exception, but whatever is happening: the exception keeps popping up.

Comment: @vascomakker.  If you don't get an exception being caught with `catch(Exception)` then you're program isn't throwing one inside your `try` block.  Maybe you should post your try block

Comment: I've added my current code. Please node that I've tried a lot, I mean A LOT, of examples from other pages of stackoverflow. All didn't help.

Comment: @vascomakker.  First, you should have your Streamwriter and Filestream in using blocks so they close automatically.  If not doing that then you should close them in a finally block as you want them to close when you don't get an exception as well.  But where is your try block?

Comment: @Harrison the Streamwriter records whatever happends in the program. If nothing happends because of the errors, I want the errors recorded so that I know something is not working.

Comment: @vascomakker, so when you got that exception, and your debug broke on it, what line of code was it on?  Please show this.  Was that line of code **inside** your try block?